# Jekyll plugin change characters

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I have made my onw jekyll plugin which gives some text special css (spoiler hider).

This is my code:

```rb
class Spoiler < Liquid::Tag
   def initialize(tag_name, input, tokens)
     super
     @input = input
   end

   def render(context)
     output = "<div class='spoiler'>" + @input + "<div>"
     return  output;
   end

end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('spoiler', Spoiler)
```

There is example how I want to use it in my markdown posts:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "testing file"
date:   2019-09-25
category: article
---

aaaaaaaaaaa  {% spoiler secret text %} bbbbbbbbbbbb
```

but this is how page looks like:

[image: screenshot of my site]

When I look in to generated source code, the text looks like this:

```html
<p>aaaaaaa &lt;div class='spoiler'&gt;secret text &lt;/div&gt; bbbbbbbb</p>
```

What should I do make jekyll plugin generate html element instead of text ?

PS: If I manually replace `&lt;` by `<` and `&gt;` by `>`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, every line separated by whitespace get rendered into an HTML `<p>` element.

To avoid generating `<p>` tags automatically, explicitly wrap lines in a `<div`>:

```html
<div>
  aaaaaaaaaaa  {% spoiler secret text %} bbbbbbbbbbbb
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But, is there another way to do that within plugin and keep markdown clean without html tags ?

Comment: Actually, no. The reason is that Jekyll's Markdown converter (wrapper for `kramdown`) is run after all Liquid in the current document has finished rendering. When `kramdown` encounters a standalone text surrounded by whitespace, it renders that text into HTML `<p>` tags.. If you want to handle this entirely via plugins, you'll have to drop using Liquid Tag and instead rely on string substitution via the `post_render` hook. You may want to look at the source code for `jemoji` plugin for reference.